# 2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discusión, elecciones

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions collected [from an earlier thread](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4372/8740) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

Due to the submission count, we have selected all provided questions as well as one of our back up questions for a total of 10 questions.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5786271a-9a61-4fb4-9d8c-7da7ed4599d0/view-source).Please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written, and also including a link to your answer on your nomination post.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

**Oh, and when you've completed your answer, please provide a link to it after this blurb here, before that set of three dashes. Please leave the list of links in the order of submission.**

To save scrolling here are links to the submissions from each candidate (in order of submission):

- [Charlie's questionnaire](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4390/12637).
- [wimi's questionnaire](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4395/24236).
- [Glorfindel's questionnaire](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4396/12637).

---

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 4. How do you feel about low Meta participation? If you think it is a problem, how would you get more people to join Meta discussions? If you think it is not a problem, what other mechanisms do you intend to use to get input from the community on proposed policy changes, events, etc.?
> 5. Quite often Spanish.SE gets answers from unregistered users that are extremely short, just in the limit of "not an answer". These answers have their value, normally because they talk about the usage of some expression in the user's location. As a moderator you are quite likely to get some flags on these posts (some automatic from the Community user and some from normal users). How do you think such answers need to be handled?
> 6. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Spanish Language Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?
> 7. What are your ideas to [engage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12023) users in the different activities of the stack (Meta participation, upvoting, participating in the review queues, chat, etc.)
> 8. For a long time, the site's graduation was a goal (or the main goal) for our community. Now that [we are no longer beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128), what do you think that should be the next milestone for our community (a shared goal across our community, that is kind of a [*big audacious hairy goal*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19161/5481)).  This could be rephrased as "What are this site's challenges and how do you plan to help empowering the community to work on them"?
> 9. From autumn 2019, the Stack Exchange community has faced several problems. Many mods have resigned (including two from Spanish.SE), many people disengaged and/or stopped participating in sites, etc. As a consequence, mod activities have slowed down and, in general, the network atmosphere is not as enthusiastic as it used to be. Taking all of this into account, why are you running for a mod position? What it is your motivation to serve the community in good faith, considering that you may face situations where you will be in a position where both Stack Exchange and the community will be pressing in different directions? / Spanish version: *Desde el otoño de 2019, la comunidad de Stack Exchange ha tenido bastantes problemas. Muchos moderadores de la red han dimitido (también en Spanish.SE), hay bastante gente que ha dejado los sitios o reducido su actividad de forma significativa, etc. Como consecuencia de ello, la actividad de moderación se ha reducido y, en general, el clima no es tan expansivo como en épocas anteriores. Conociendo todo esto, ¿por qué te presentas a moderador y con qué finalidad? ¿Qué te motiva a servir a la comunidad con buena fe, habida cuenta que puedes encontrarte en más de una ocasión en fuego cruzado (Stack Exchange por un lado, la comunidad por el otro)?*
> 10. What contribution(s) to Meta (no more than three examples) would you say best exemplify your prospective moderation style?

Answer (score 8):

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Moderators are just "exception handlers". Every user with a bit of experience may help moderate the site, but there are some situations standard users cannot handle, and is in those cases where moderators step in. They may have the last word in a debate, decide what to do with questionable questions or answers, help users who have gone the wrong way, mediate in disputes between users, and so on. And ultimately they may speak with the Community Managers for help in the most complicated issues.

In few words, moderators just help the community to keep the site neat and tidy and peaceful.

Moderators are also mediators between the users and the highest instances of the Stack Exchange network, but there's another question for that.

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

Users usually learn what they can and cannot do by experience. In most cases users learn what to do and what not to do when a moderator modifies or removes a comment. But if a user keeps on generating debates that do not drive the conversation to a good place, I can always have a private conversation with the given user, the chat system allows for private rooms for that, so the conversation remains private for the user and the moderator. The next step would be a temporary ban from the system, but I consider that a bit counterproductive and should be only done in flagrant cases.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I would just ask the other moderator for their reasons. Talking is the way for almost everything here. Ultimately I would ask the other moderator to check with the rest of moderators before closing or deleting a debatable question.

> 4. How do you feel about low Meta participation? If you think it is a problem, how would you get more people to join Meta discussions? If you think it is not a problem, what other mechanisms do you intend to use to get input from the community on proposed policy changes, events, etc.?

I'm not sure that a low participation on Meta is a bad thing, it may just indicate that the users are happy with the site as it is. Nonetheless, Meta is a good site for users to decide what to do with the main site. I am known among some users as the guy who invented [translation-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-golf), and I am also known for trying to push the limits of the site once and again (see my cross-over questions *[Spanish Language Meets...](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22spanish%20language%20meets%22)*). One of them even got closed as off-topic, but it really doesn't matter as long we all learn to drive the site to a better place. I'm sure there's still a lot of questions to ask, we just need to know where they are.

> 5. Quite often Spanish.SE gets answers from unregistered users that are extremely short, just in the limit of "not an answer". These answers have their value, normally because they talk about the usage of some expression in the user's location. As a moderator you are quite likely to get some flags on these posts (some automatic from the Community user and some from normal users). How do you think such answers need to be handled?

Answers from unregistered users usually fall in three categories. First is the answer that is a comment to the question or to another answer, that can be converted to a comment after leaving a message to the user. Second is the totally unrelated answer that does not attempt to answer the question and does not serve as a comment, those answers are usually deleted (I always try to leave a comment before), specially if they already have some close votes. Third one are the debatable answers, which may contain a bit of useful information. I then leave the community decide, and only take action if the flag is still active after some days.

Well, there is a fourth category. The user with experience in the site that wants to keep anonymous but contributes very good questions and answers, but that is not what we are discussing here. :-)

> 6. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Spanish Language Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?

The main problem I think is an old one: low participation in the main site. While other language stacks may have a steady stream of several questions a day, sometimes I see several days pass between one question and the next one, then some days we may have three or four questions in a row. I honestly don't know how to handle that after all this years.

As for the site itself, it requires little work as we have quite a good community so no problems on that side.

> 7. What are your ideas to [engage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12023) users in the different activities of the stack (Meta participation, upvoting, participating in the review queues, chat, etc.)

I don't have an answer for that. I've been just keeping the site alive, neat and tidy with the help of the rest of users. But I reckon there have been other moderators who have managed better than me at Meta and at engaging users, and even now they still do. So please do not let my nomination be the only one. :-)

> 8. For a long time, the site's graduation was a goal (or the main goal) for our community. Now that [we are no longer beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128), what do you think that should be the next milestone for our community (a shared goal across our community, that is kind of a [*big audacious hairy goal*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19161/5481)).  This could be rephrased as "What are this site's challenges and how do you plan to help empowering the community to work on them"?

I think a proper challenge for the community could be searching for more ways to broad the scope of the site while keeping the focus on the language. Maybe allowing some types of questions we still do not accept, or finding new ways of asking, who knows... Of course Meta should be the proper place for those debates, and people would be invited to participate by featuring the questions.

> 9. From autumn 2019, the Stack Exchange community has faced several problems. Many mods have resigned (including two from Spanish.SE), many people disengaged and/or stopped participating in sites, etc. As a consequence, mod activities have slowed down and, in general, the network atmosphere is not as enthusiastic as it used to be. Taking all of this into account, why are you running for a mod position? What it is your motivation to serve the community in good faith, considering that you may face situations where you will be in a position where both Stack Exchange and the community will be pressing in different directions?

Yes, and I have noted the poorer atmosphere specially in the Spanish Language site. That could be another big challenge for the site, to restore the golden days of the site we had two or three years ago. Nonetheless, the fact that moderators are in the middle of the *battle* between users and the Stack Exchange network is quite interesting because we get to be the spokepersons for the site community in case the site decides something, but we also get to be the *news announcers* for everything the higher instances decide, and it's our task to help the community implement the news. And in case of dispute between the parts there's always... talking. Talking solves everything. And empathy.

Last year's events caught me as a newly appointed moderator and I reckon I did not do my best, but here I am still as moderator. Things can be talked about, specially if people talk with an open mind.

> 10. What contribution(s) to Meta (no more than three examples) would you say best exemplify your prospective moderation style?

- [Let's solve our differences by talking, with honor and
  sportsmanship](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3302/12637).
- [Always willing to help](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4358/12637), [no matter the size of the problem](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4393/12637).
- And of course, my [legendary](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/12637) [contributions](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3110/12637) [to help expanding](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3242/12637) the scope of the site. :-)

Comment: +1. Yo apoyo tu candidatura. Gracias por todo lo que haces por el stack. Dicho eso, yo no estoy de acuerdo con la valoración que haces sobre Meta (`low participation on Meta [..] may just indicate that the users are happy with the site as it is`). Eso significaría que estamos de acuerdo también con la baja participación en el sitio principal. Bien podríamos decir que la participación en Meta/Main "es la que es". No sé si estamos contentos con el sitio como es o si es que nos hemos resignado por unas razones u otras, y hemos asumido la apatía generalizada, que ya ni discutimos en Meta.

Comment: @Diego sí, creo que no me he explicado bien. Hablaba en general, no refiriéndome al sitio de español en particular. Y me refería a ello como una posibilidad. Eso no quita para que la realidad sea otra, y se acerque más a lo que tú dices en el caso de nuestro sitio en concreto. Cuando terminen las elecciones podríamos empezar una ronda de preguntas para tomar el pulso al sitio y ver qué acciones podemos llevar a cabo.

Comment: @Diego ¡y gracias por tu apoyo! :-)

Comment: Gracias por presentarte de nuevo al cargo. El sitio ha estado tranquilo este último año, seguramente parte importante de ello es gracias a tu trabajo tras bastidores. Seguramente ha faltado algo de empuje en debates en Meta y similares, algo achacable también a la comunidad en su conjunto. Ojalá salga un equipo de moderadores en plural y podáis hacer cosas y también descansar, que también es importante y difícil cuando se es moderador. Cuenta con mi voto también.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' gracias por tu apoyo una vez más. Por ahora estoy ilusionado con la posibilidad de tener un compañero, y por el estilo de wimi creo que nos vamos a complementar muy bien. Ojalá se presenten más candidatos, pero de momento esto ya será una mejora que espero que redunde en un mejor sitio para todos.

Answer (score 6):

#### [wimi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/24236/wimi)'s questionnaire

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

As has often been said during the last 11 years, [moderators are exception handlers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). They are there to fix the problems that the community cannot solve, or that require faster action than the community can provide. The most important "exceptions" are disputes between users, but abusive content (especially in comments) that needs to be deleted quickly also qualifies.

I agree with Stack Exchange's view that a moderator should ideally do as little as possible. Wherever possible, I would let the community reach decisions using the available tools (close votes, delete votes, etc.) before intervening.

It has also been mentioned before that part of a moderator's job is being a **janitor**. This is also partly true, especially regarding [tag housekeeping](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2962/24236). If I become a moderator, I will start dealing with at least [this](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3298/24236).

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

The first line of action would be to deal with the content itself, to make sure that the site is clean. If the generation of controversial content became a pattern, I would first try to talk to the user privately, and try to make them see how their posts are generating disputes and try to convince them to avoid that kind of posts, while also listening to their version of the story. I would expect most engaged users to be willing to fix the problem. However, if the user persists and generates problems in the community (especially, if they start to make the site uncomfortable for other users), I would have to start using the stronger tools (i.e., suspensions, following the general advice to start with a warning, then suspend for a short time if the behavior is repeated, then go on to longer suspensions). Luckily, it seems that we are unlikely to have to reach that point on Spanish.SE.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

Communication is key. Moderators are a team, so if moderators disagree on their decisions, I would try to talk to the other moderator and reach an agreement. As long as privacy concerns allow this, my suggested way to reach an agreement would be to ask the community on Meta.

> 4. How do you feel about low Meta participation? If you think it is a problem, how would you get more people to join Meta discussions? If you think it is not a problem, what other mechanisms do you intend to use to get input from the community on proposed policy changes, events, etc.?

Low Meta participation means that there are few users that are involved enough in the site that they are interested in policies, events, and other meta discussions. Too low participation is a problem because it makes it difficult to know what the community wants and make decisions based on that. Users that do not participate on Meta are more likely to stay while they like the site, and leave when a change happens that they do not like. Without their input, we cannot prevent that.

I think users need to like the main site before they decide to participate on Meta. So the first step to increase participation is to have an attractive main site. Then, whenever the comments on a post lead to a discussion that would be better to have on Meta, we should actively encourage that. It can be as simple as a discussion on which question is a duplicate of which. That is how I started to participate on our Meta anyway...

> 5. Quite often Spanish.SE gets answers from unregistered users that are extremely short, just in the limit of "not an answer". These answers have their value, normally because they talk about the usage of some expression in the user's location. As a moderator you are quite likely to get some flags on these posts (some automatic from the Community user and some from normal users). How do you think such answers need to be handled?

The community has tools to moderate answers, so in case of doubt I would let the community decide what to do from the review queues (VLQ/NAA). I would leave a comment suggesting ways in which the author could improve the answer. In general, I agree with [the general sentiment on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264293/643262) that "bad/wrong answers should be downvoted, not deleted" and "non-answers should be deleted". So if it answers the question, I would be more inclined to leave it there, comment and possibly downvote if the comment is not addressed. But the community can, and will, sometimes override me on this.

> 6. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Spanish Language Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?

The biggest problem is probably low participation, especially low involvement in Meta discussions (and low engagement leading to the lack of moderator candidates). As I wrote on my answer to question 4, making the main site interesting is the first step to fix that, and encouraging the use of Meta to solve discussions/disputes is the next step. The lack of moderator candidates is much harder to fix, as moderating is a voluntary job, and the motivation do it should come from the candidate personally. The relatively recent problems between the community and SE have damaged this motivation quite strongly on our site. I hope that the relation with SE will slowly improve, and next year maybe more people are motivated to moderate.

> 7. What are your ideas to [engage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12023) users in the different activities of the stack (Meta participation, upvoting, participating in the review queues, chat, etc.)

As I said before: have an interesting Main site. Be nice to new users, acknowledge it when they write good posts, make them feel motivated to keep contributing. Luckily, we do not seem to have a problem with the review queues or with voting, and those things probably come more naturally to users than Meta participation.

> 8. For a long time, the site's graduation was a goal (or the main goal) for our community. Now that [we are no longer beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128), what do you think that should be the next milestone for our community (a shared goal across our community, that is kind of a [*big audacious hairy goal*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19161/5481)).  This could be rephrased as "What are this site's challenges and how do you plan to help empowering the community to work on them"?

The main goal is still to increase participation. We are no longer beta, but our participation levels are not better than in the beta stage. As a *big audacious hairy goal*, I would suggest getting to add new entries to our list of "[achievements related to presence in the media](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2940/24236)". Some nice stuff was achieved there, it would be nice to keep it up!

> 9. From autumn 2019, the Stack Exchange community has faced several problems. Many mods have resigned (including two from Spanish.SE), many people disengaged and/or stopped participating in sites, etc. As a consequence, mod activities have slowed down and, in general, the network atmosphere is not as enthusiastic as it used to be. Taking all of this into account, why are you running for a mod position? What it is your motivation to serve the community in good faith, considering that you may face situations where you will be in a position where both Stack Exchange and the community will be pressing in different directions? / Spanish version: *Desde el otoño de 2019, la comunidad de Stack Exchange ha tenido bastantes problemas. Muchos moderadores de la red han dimitido (también en Spanish.SE), hay bastante gente que ha dejado los sitios o reducido su actividad de forma significativa, etc. Como consecuencia de ello, la actividad de moderación se ha reducido y, en general, el clima no es tan expansivo como en épocas anteriores. Conociendo todo esto, ¿por qué te presentas a moderador y con qué finalidad? ¿Qué te motiva a servir a la comunidad con buena fe, habida cuenta que puedes encontrarte en más de una ocasión en fuego cruzado (Stack Exchange por un lado, la comunidad por el otro)?*

My motivation to run for moderator is that **I like the site, and I want to keep it running**. As mentioned in my nomination, there are users that have much longer experience than me on the site, and would be great moderators. But I understand that those users are not motivated to moderate, some due to the dispute with SE, some due to other personal reasons. Being a relatively newer user, the problems with SE have not hurt my motivation so strongly, and I think I can moderate well (enough) in this situation. I will, to the extent possible, put the interests of the Spanish.SE community first when dealing with SE. My experience in the last year is that the changes to the Code of Conduct did not cause big problems in our site. We had a user who found it important to keep their gender hidden, and we had some discussion about it. You can see my [contribution to that discussion](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3259/24236), which I think was well received by the community and by the user themselves.

> 10. What contribution(s) to Meta (no more than three examples) would you say best exemplify your prospective moderation style?

In these times, the first one is definitely [the answer I just mentioned](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3259/24236). You can expect this kind of moderation from me in this issue (and in other issues): apply [common sense](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/pido-permiso-para-usar-en-los-adjetivos-de-mis-posts-cuando-hablo-de-m%c3%ad-mism#comment6505_3259), and respect individual users' wishes as long as that is possible (i.e., as long as that does not hurt other users).

The second one would be [this one](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3261/24236), which shows that I will **get input from the community** before making decisions. As mentioned before, unilateral decisions should be reserved for exceptional cases.

The third one is [this one](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3253/24236), which I wrote at the beginning of my time here. With this I show that I want to **trust new users**, and not make them feel like "new contributors going through an initiation test" for a too long time. Suggest ways to improve not-so-good answers, praise the first good answer, but let them feel like a full member of the community as soon as it is clear that they do not need more guidance.

Comment: Sobre la pregunta 5 de las respuestas cortas hace tiempo sugerí (e implementé tras conseguir bastante apoyo) [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Me parece que funcionó razonablemente bien, pero últimamente está bastante parado. ¿Cuál es tu opinión al respecto?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' sí, "community wiki" es una buena solución cuando las preguntas se empiezan a llenar de respuestas regionales. De hecho tiene sentido iniciar ya las preguntas que preguntan por listas como CW. Yo me refería más a respuestas cortas "aisladas".

Comment: Sobre la teoría de moderación, hace un par de años se actualizó y la vigente vendría a ser [Our Theory of Moderation, Re-visited](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) dando cinco claves sobre el trabajo del moderador: _Trust. Support. Agency. Accountability. Autonomy_. Para mí, es un cambio en el sentido que se busca salir del _exception handler_ para pasar a un rol algo más proactivo. Algo así como lo que se suele pedir a los usuarios 10K que muestran más interés, pero con el añadido de las herramientas de moderador.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' sí, hombre, con lo bien que nos teníamos wimi y yo aprendido lo de ser un _exception handler_ no vengas ahora a echárnoslo por tierra. :-D Pues nada, a actualizarse...

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' mm, leyendo ese artículo, parece que esos cinco pilares (Trust. Support. Agency. Accountability. Autonomy) son las obligaciones de SE en su trato con los moderadores (dicen: "Here’s how we think about our obligations to the hundreds of incredible people elected by our community"). En cualquier caso, no es tan importante: por supuesto que no voy a seguir al pie de la letra lo que pone en esos artículos, sino que me adaptaré a las necesidades de la comunidad.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, leí mal (siempre con prisas). Dicho lo cual, me gustan esos cinco pilares.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' en particular, "trust, agency, autonomy" son parecidos y es una de las cosas que menciono repetidamente en mis respuestas: dar poder a la comunidad, respetar sus decisiones. "Support", haré lo que pueda: en particular, tenía pensado dar un email de contacto para temas sensibles de moderación si soy elegido, ya que SE no proporciona ningún canal privado. Y "accountability", por descontado: cada uno es responsable de lo que hace, y yo no soy una excepción. No creo que mi estilo de moderación fuera a estar muy lejos de esos pilares :)

Comment: El tema en Spanish es que los moderadores suelen ser usuarios que ya de por sí tenían actividad alta (como [comentaba el año pasado](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3173/1674)), por lo que la línea entre ser "bienvenidores" al sitio y moderadores a veces es algo fina. Lo de "accountability" debe trabajarse más en este sitio, es bueno que se confronten opiniones y sensaciones para ir estableciendo consensos y que no se enquisten los problemas. Gracias por tus respuestas y éxito.

Comment: +1 para Wimi también. Creo que es totalmente legítimo querer seguir mejorando el sitio y hacerlo como moderador (es una experiencia más que te llevas). Yo también estoy de acuerdo en que la falta de participación es un problema. Lo que creo que habría que discutir es si es causa o consecuencia, o cuánto tiene de cada una.

Comment: Sobre esas cinco claves del moderador "Trust. Support. Agency. Accountability. Autonomy", leyendo la ["repuesta de SE a la Carta Lavanda"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354978/356575) (que han puesto _featured_), me queda claro que la comunidad sigue dividida (ni siquiera sobre el uso o no de [neo]pronombres, sino sobre si debemos, o podemos, tener una discusión sobre el asunto). No creo que SE pueda cerrar esta herida, teniendo en cuenta la pérdida de confianza, y eso puede afectar a esos cinco pilares del moderador.

Comment: @Diego sí, hay claramente distintas opiniones en la comunidad. Pero distintas opiniones sobre el uso de pronombres habría con o sin "superpatinazo" de SE (Monica etc.). Yo creo que algún paso atrás sí que ha dado SE en el tema pronombres: han incluso [aceptado el uso del generic he](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/643262). Pero la división de opiniones no la van a arreglar ni SE ni nadie. El objetivo es que esa división de opiniones no lleve a peleas, resentimientos, etc., al menos aquí en Spanish.SE.

Comment: @Diego y por supuesto, la pérdida de confianza puede que cambie las relaciones entre SE y los moderadores y dañe esos cinco pilares, por ejemplo la [polémica que hubo con el tema de los featured posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343527/643262), donde SE tomó el "mando" y se "saltó" lo del "trust, agency, autonomy". Pero quiero creer que aún con esos problemas se puede trabajar para tener una comunidad activa, inclusiva y razonable aquí en Spanish.SE (es decir, como la actual pero esperemls que más grande). Veremos si el tiempo me da la razón.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Glorfindel](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-36864)'s answers to the questionnaire:

I've already answered a few of these questionnaires across the network, but most Stack Exchange communities aren't that different from each other, and I still stand behind answers I gave in the past.

> 1. In your opinion, what do moderators do?

Moderators are first and foremost elected by the community to represent their interests in every way possible. I especially identify with the interests of those *studying* the Spanish language. In general, those interests may be helping with welcoming new users, handling flags, doing a lot of reviews, and being a bridge between the community and Stack Exchange the company, among other things. It sometimes means putting your own ideas second, third, or even ignoring them altogether. Writing answers (or questions) is not one of their primary tasks; that's where subject matter experts are for (though being both is perfectly possible, see @Charlie).

> 2. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?

[Being nice](/conduct) is very important to the success of Stack Exchange; more important than posting good answers (or questions, for that matter). I'd remind this user (in a polite but strict way) to change their behaviour or face the consequences in the form of a suspension. There are enough other users who can write those valuable answers instead.

> 3. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

I'd discuss this with them in a private chatroom. I might bring in a third moderator as well if I feel we need to make a tough decision, so that it can be a decision of a majority. There's no need doing this in public and risk harming the trust the community has in the moderator team.

> 4. How do you feel about low Meta participation? If you think it is a problem, how would you get more people to join Meta discussions? If you think it is not a problem, what other mechanisms do you intend to use to get input from the community on proposed policy changes, events, etc.?

Low Meta participation isn't necessarily a problem when things are going smooth. It *is* a problem if the community is facing a crisis. Moderators can help by identifying the problems (preferably before they become too big), start the debate with an inviting Meta question and making it [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). We do have to face the reality that many users are here just to share their knowledge or get their questions answered, and don't have any interest in Meta (which is absolutely fine – they just miss opportunities to make a big impact on the community).

> 5. Quite often Spanish.SE gets answers from unregistered users that are extremely short, just in the limit of "not an answer". These answers have their value, normally because they talk about the usage of some expression in the user's location. As a moderator you are quite likely to get some flags on these posts (some automatic from the Community user and some from normal users). How do you think such answers need to be handled?

On English Language Learners, I'll usually leave a comment like these:

- While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer](/help/how-to-answer).
- Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of the language well and may be deleted.

I might be able to edit answers like that, but as the saying goes: it's better to teach someone to fish rather than give them a fish. I vividly remember one of my first answers in the network getting a comment like that and that was one of the key moments for me.

> 6. In your opinion, what is the biggest problem/challenge Spanish Language Stack Exchange is currently facing? How would you propose to solve it?

There aren't enough questions. The [Area 51 statistics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) are telling. Unfortunately, I'm not too much of a community builder, and don't know of any way to attract more people to Spanish Language Stack Exchange. As often in business, it's easier to retain existing users than try to gain new ones. We *can* do our best to try to keep all new users who do come here engaged, by treating them respectfully and tell them how to improve their experience here. The Stack Exchange Q&A format takes a while to get used to.

> 7. What are your ideas to [engage](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12023) users in the different activities of the stack (Meta participation, upvoting, participating in the review queues, chat, etc.)

We could post some Meta questions about the [importance of voting](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2639/13538), reviewing etc. and make them [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) so that more people will see them. We could also leave a comment on posts by users who just passed the 350 / 500 / 1000 reputation mark to congratulate them with this milestone and remind them of the existence of review queues. (Technically, that's not where comments are for, but there isn't a real comment problem here.)

> 8. For a long time, the site's graduation was a goal (or the main goal) for our community. Now that [we are no longer beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128), what do you think that should be the next milestone for our community (a shared goal across our community, that is kind of a [*big audacious hairy goal*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19161/5481)).  This could be rephrased as "What are this site's challenges and how do you plan to help empowering the community to work on them"?

See 6.

> 9. From Autumn 2019, the Stack Exchange community has faced several problems. Many mods have resigned (including two from Spanish.SE), many people disengaged and/or stopped participating in sites, etc. As a consequence, mod activities have slowed down and, in general, the network atmosphere is not as enthusiastic as it used to be. Taking all of this into account, why are you running for a mod position? What it is your motivation to serve the community in good faith, considering that you may face situations where you will be in a position where both Stack Exchange and the community will be pressing in different directions? / Spanish version: *Desde el otoño de 2019, la comunidad de Stack Exchange ha tenido bastantes problemas. Muchos moderadores de la red han dimitido (también en Spanish.SE), hay bastante gente que ha dejado los sitios o reducido su actividad de forma significativa, etc. Como consecuencia de ello, la actividad de moderación se ha reducido y, en general, el clima no es tan expansivo como en épocas anteriores. Conociendo todo esto, ¿por qué te presentas a moderador y con qué finalidad? ¿Qué te motiva a servir a la comunidad con buena fe, habida cuenta que puedes encontrarte en más de una ocasión en fuego cruzado (Stack Exchange por un lado, la comunidad por el otro)?*

Needless to say, I'm far from happy with last year's events. I do see some progress in how Stack Exchange the company is treating the communities (and individuals) right now, which is one of the reasons I'm still participating in the network, and willing to participate in restoring the community's trust in Stack Exchange and vice versa. See also my answer to question 1.; *moderators are first and foremost elected by the community to represent their interests in every way possible.* If I ever feel there are *irreconcilable* differences between the community and Stack Exchange, I'll probably quit (as a moderator but also as a regular user), but right now I don't feel this is the case.

> 10. What contribution(s) to Meta (no more than three examples) would you say best exemplify your prospective moderation style?

As a moderator, I'm at my best as a janitor (which isn't too visible on Meta) and as a Stack Exchange knowledge base (see my [two](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4347) [relevant](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4355/13538) answers here). Perhaps [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335074/295232) (to which I've posted two answers as well) best exemplifies who I am, as a person but in particular as a moderator: trying to be neutral and objective at all times.

Comment: I very much appreciate your job around Stack Exchange, but I cannot understand this nomination (that [would currently mean you being appointed](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4364/1674)). In 4 years in the site you've asked 2 questions and answered 2 in Meta. I think this is far from enough to grasp the idea of the community. I would suggest spending some time on the site and _then_ running for moderator in subsequent elections.

Comment: I completely understand, that's why I wrote in my nomination *Since I'm far from the ideal candidate, I've waited until now to nominate; I'm sincerely hoping other better suited users will take the job.* Someone else might be holding back their nomination, fearing that they might end up last in the election. Rest assured, they'll beat me.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I'm also surprised by this nomination, and Glorfindel may not know how this community works, but he's already a mod in three other sites so he may help us with knowledge about how to handle some situations we may have not faced yet, and how to improve the way we work. And we can always help him with what he doesn't know, so he can get the grasp of our community as time goes by. Given the situation I'm glad about this nomination.

Comment: So the situation is: the site has some problems, one of them being lack of interest of people to nominate as moderators. Instead of going to the root of it, you suggest to have a random nominee (that anybody would beat, in your own words) so that we cover more moderator vacancies. I don't this is a fix but a workaround. You well know I appreciate your work around SE, we have "met" several times in Meta.SE around different issues, but I don't think this is the way to go. Good luck to you all.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' I had thought something like this might happen, that is why I asked the opinion of the community before nominating myself. There was an [interest check](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3313/24236) a while ago where it was clear that very few people would step up... I think this could have been solved by opening only two moderator positions instead of three. Or by imposing a threshold in the votes for a candidate to be appointed, let's say some percentage of the winner's votes. But now it is too late for that.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' About Glorfindel's nomination, I would also prefer someone familiar with the community, otherwise it's hard to apply his first sentence, "Moderators are first and foremost elected by the community to represent their interests in every way possible". Most important to me is that moderators have support from the community, as exercising "power" without support is very difficult. If it turns out that there is this support, then I am fine with the nomination. If Glorfindel is appointed with little or no support, then I think that something in the system should be changed.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' On the positive side, we know that he knows how to moderate, so I do not think he would do a bad job. Of course, whatever the results of the election, I will accept them and work together with everyone (mods and non-mods) to make the most of the situation.

Comment: @wimi yes, sure Glorfindel can and will do great if appointed/elected. Btw, some sites post a prenomination where people can suggest others to run for moderator (we tried this last year, then deleted). Also, note moderators of a site are not isolated: there are plenty of network wide resources for them: a chat (Teachers' Lounge), a direct contact system with CMs, and a Stack Overflow for Teams. So more than "network knowledge" what I think we need in a moderation team is "Spanish.SE knowledge", plus some women, plus some people in South America.

Comment: Coincido con fedorqui. Glorfindel tiene mucha experiencia como moderador y será de gran ayuda en el sitio (aunque yo apenas le conozco actividad en este, aparte de aprobar sus _edits_ a otros posts en las colas). Lo malo, peor en mi opinión que la escasa participación en Main o Meta, es que en esta comunidad **tendemos a actuar sobre las consecuencias de los problemas y no sobre las causas**. Pensaba que las elecciones fracasarían, lo discutiríamos en Meta y aprenderíamos algo, pero hemos encontrado la forma de solucionarlo sin enfrentarnos al problema de la falta de interés por las elecciones